# How to set outlook folder initial view programatically

Tags: outlook

I want to set a public folder to have an initial view (custom view), I know how to do it manually on outlook 2007, however, I cannot find any property or method i can use in the Interop (Folder and MAPI folder) that can do this.

After a few hours of googling, i came out the following:

```
Imports NUnit.Framework
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net.Mime
Imports System.Net

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

<TestFixture()>
Public Class TestOutlook
    <Explicit()>
    <Test()>
    Public Sub TestSetFolderInitialView()
        Dim ol As New Outlook.Application
        Dim exCatched As Exception = Nothing
        Try
            ' Get My Mailbox 
            Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Nothing
            For i As Integer = 0 To ol.Session.Folders.Count - 1
                myFolder = ol.Session.Folders(i + 1)
                If myFolder.Name = "Mailbox - Rex" Then ' Change it to your mail box name
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            ' Get the folder I want to Set initial view
            Dim testFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Nothing
            If myFolder IsNot Nothing Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To myFolder.Folders.Count - 1
                    Dim pFolder = myFolder.Folders(i + 1)
                    If pFolder.Name = "Inbox" Then
                        For Each fol As Outlook.MAPIFolder In pFolder.Folders
                            If fol.Name = "TestFolder" Then
                                testFolder = fol
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            If testFolder IsNot Nothing Then
                Try
                    ' Create a test view
                    Dim newVw = CType(testFolder.Views.Add("RexTest-" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss"),
                                                                   Outlook.OlViewType.olTableView,
                                                                   Outlook.OlViewSaveOption.olViewSaveOptionThisFolderEveryone), 
                                             Outlook.TableView)
                    newVw.LockUserChanges = True
                    newVw.Save()
                    newVw.Apply()

                    ' PR_DEFAULT_VIEW_ENTRYID:
                    Dim ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/"
                    Dim PR_DEFAULT_VIEW_ENTRYID = "0x36160102"
                    Dim PR_FOLDER_XVIEWINFO_E = "0x36E00102"
                    Dim defaultVw = testFolder.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(ns & PR_DEFAULT_VIEW_ENTRYID)
                    Dim xVwInfo = testFolder.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(ns & PR_FOLDER_XVIEWINFO_E)

                    ' the defaultVw is nothing for the first time (actually throw exception)
                    ' if i manually change it from the outlook, 
                    '   the value will be something like: 000000004B593F3D35EF8C42AB181C105AE444D40700E46C905CB9ABE446AA44351902AFC40E000026BF7A8C000040DB82FE9B98724F9B222A9C9BDB42CD0000005CF0280000

                    ' **** The problem is how to get the correct binary data for the newly created view so i can set it like this: *****
                    'testFolder.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(ns & PR_DEFAULT_VIEW_ENTRYID, testFolder.PropertyAccessor.StringToBinary(newVw.Name))
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' _log.Warn(String.Format("Error set initial view {0} to folder - {1}", newVw.Name, testFolder.Name), ex)
                    exCatched = ex
                    ' First time error 'The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36160102" is unknown or cannot be found' will be shown
                    ' If we set the initial view of the folder in the outlook, this error will go away
                End Try
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)
            exCatched = ex
        Finally
            If ol IsNot Nothing Then
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ol)
                ol = Nothing
            End If
        End Try

        If exCatched IsNot Nothing Then
            Throw exCatched
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now the only left part is how to get the correct binary data from the newly created view. some clue to manipulate the binary value: http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.messaging.narkive.com/x1fNHHA5/default-view

however it was written in a different language and I got no idea how to make it in vb or c#.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MAPIFolder.CurrentView and MAPIFolder.Views?

Comment: Yes, tried all the CurrentView and Views, seems I can apply a view only, but not able to set it as the initial view of the folder.

Comment: looks this solve the problem, but no idea how to write it in c# or VB -- http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.messaging.narkive.com/x1fNHHA5/default-view

Comment: You can set any MAPI property on the folder using MAPIFolder.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty.

Comment: you are right that I can use the PropertyAccessor to set it, and I have found two properties related to this - PR_DEFAULT_VIEW_ENTRYID (0x36160102) and PR_FOLDER_XVIEWINFO_E (0x36E00102). but the problem is how to get the correct binary data to populate into these property? I've edited the post with my test case, please help

Comment: Try to set the view in the Outlook UI, then look at these properties with OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - click IMAPIFolder button, select the property (e.g. PR_FOLDER_XVIEWINFO_E), click the button next to the "Value" edit box, then click "Copy as Hex". You should be able to hardcode that value in your code.

Comment: actually i can get the binary via VB code if the view is already set manually at outlook, see the test case I posted. But at my situation - the folder and view will be created at run time, I need a way to get the correct binary data for the newly created view.

Comment: AFAIK that binary data only includes the view name and does not differ between installations, so you should be able to hardcode it without knowing what it is actually inside.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work: i did a test with two folders with same custom view name (i have to use custom view at folder level, otherwise it won't be allowed to set as initial view), and the retrieved binary data are different. I think there must be a way to manipulate the binary according to the path of the folder (or something similar). any hint?